# Tailpiece too long for new chrome J-Bend in kitchen sink drain repair

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, kitchen-sink

The j-Bend of my kitchen sink drain pipe rusted through and started leaking. I bought a new 1.5" j-Bend at Home Depot. Only when I got it home did I notice that the top part of the J is different than my old part. The old part allowed the tailpiece pipe to go down further into the J than the new part does. Because of the difference in size, the new part can't accommodate enough of the tailpiece to allow the other end of the J to mate with the other piece of the P-Trap.

I looked online and couldn't find any j-bends that are sized like my old one.

So what should I do?  Should I get a hacksaw and cut the tailpiece down to size?  Or should I go to a plumbing supply store to see if I can get a matching j-Bend?  Or is there another option?

Other than the J-Bend with a hole in it, the other parts of the drain are in good shape-- no visible corrosion, no leaks, etc. so I'd prefer to avoid replacing more than I need to.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim the tailpiece to fit. A pipe cutter would be a bit more suitable than a hacksaw, but if you only have a hacksaw, just clean up well with a file after sawing.

New tailpieces come quite long so they can be trimmed to fit.

Comment: I would add that if you do use a hack saw to cut off the existing drop pipe it may be wise to remove it for the cutting operation. It could be difficult to hold the pipe securely when it is in place and the resultant back and forth forces applied during cutting could affect the integrity of the joint and drain assembly at the top of the drop pipe. When it is apart it is also an excellent time to replace any of the sealing rings and washers with fresh new ones.

Comment: I agree with the above answer and comment, if you insist on using the old existing parts. However, it would be my recommendation to replace the tailpiece and p-trap entirely, with ABS or PVC components.